# Relation of $f : V \rightarrow V$ and $Id_v$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image]

(There's a slight typo in the question it should say $\Phi : \mathbb{F^n} \rightarrow V$ )

So in this question I can understand the matrix A, which just follows a commutative diagram.

But I don't even know where to start on the actual proof. It appears that $f = \lambda Id_V$ is representative of an eigenvector, but we haven't done eigenvectors yet for this class or up to this point in the textbook, so I don't think eigenvectors and eigenvalues can be used to solve this problem.

It seems to me that the map $f : V \rightarrow V$ is equivalent to $Id_V$

If anyone can give me a hint toward solving this problem that would be great

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to rephrase the question in terms of commutation of $f$ with certain endomorphisms ?

Comment: The question is asking which $A$ commute with all non-singular matrices. It's almost the same as determining the centre of the matrix algebra.

Comment: @Max , hmm , ok, so an endomorphism is a homomorphism from one object to itself. I can't see how f could commute through any other endomorphisms that are not f.